# How to send data form android?

Tags: java, android

Here is my `OnClick` method:

`ib_wyslij.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new MyAsyncTask().execute(zam.klient.getNazwa(),zam.klient.getNip(),zam.klient.getAdres());


        }
    });
```

And here is my AsycTask class:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(null, null, null);
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void postData(String nazwa, String adres, String nip) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://www.msinzynierka.cba.pl/executeConn.php");


            try {
                // Add your data

                KlientNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                KlientNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Kli_imie", nazwa));
                KlientNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Kli_adres", adres));
                KlientNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Kli_nr_telefonu",nip));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        KlientNameValuePairs));



                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

I want to ask how to make it works ? I've got `NullPointerException` here:
But the values are in. I make Toast for all of them and values are good. How can I make it works ? Any ideas are welcome

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(zam.klient.getNazwa(),zam.klient.getNip(),zam.klient.getAdres());
```

Comment: @codeMagic you're an expert in it ;) could you give me some advice ?

Comment: Czy jesteś z Polski ;-)?

Comment: Tak, a czemu pytasz ? :)

Comment: A tak z ciekawości :-) Nie ma tu zbyt dużo Polaków :(

Comment: @Ty221 English language only here please.  It is in the [FAQ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing 3 null values in your `AsyncTask`, from your code:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    postData(null, null, null);
    return null;

}
```

This should be:  `postData(params[0], params[1], params[2]);`

Also, because of how you are arranging your strings when calling your execute method, you might want to rearrange your parameters in `postData(String nazwa, String adres, String nip)` to `postData(String nazwa, String nip, String adres)`.

Comment: there is still nullPointer in execute